# Javascript HTML string - inject into document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

This is the HTML I have:

```
 <ul id="myUL">
</ul>
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
var myString = "    &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.google.comp&quot;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;    &lt;li&gt;Something Else&lt;/li&gt;"

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = myString;
$("#myUL").append(div.innerHTML);
```

This is what I recieve:

```
<ul id="myUL" >
   &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="www.google.com"&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;    &lt;li&gt;Something Else&lt;/li&gt;
</ul>
```

This is what I want to recieve:

```
<ul id="myUL">
   <li>
    <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
  </li>    
  <li>
    Something Else
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Any advices?

Comment: We use `&lt;` to *prevent* that character being interpreted as the opening of an HTML tag, which is the exact opposite of what you want; simply use the characters, for example, `<` rather than encoding them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly note that you can't append a `div` to a `ul` as it's invalid HTML. `ul` can only contain `li` as children.

The issue itself is because your string contains escaped HTML. You can either use a plain string:

```js
var myString = '<li><a href="http://www.google.comp">Google</a></li><li>Something Else</li>';
$("#myUL").append(myString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

Or you can unescape the string:

```js
var myString = "&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.google.comp&quot;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;    &lt;li&gt;Something Else&lt;/li&gt;"
$("#myUL").append(htmlDecode(myString));

function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript) for more information on the `htmlDecode()` function.

Comment: To be clear, you most certainly *can* append a `div` into a `ul`, in the sense that, invalid or not, pretty much every browser will let you do it (and will even render the result more or less consistently). The fact that you can do it in practice, however, doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen it won't throw an error but the browser won't let you do it. If you check in the DOM inspector the `div` will be placed outside of the `ul`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Strange, that's not [what I observe.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj2n8.png) (And yes, both Firefox and Chrome behave the same way. Unfortunately I don't have IE / Edge available to test with.)

Answer (score 3):

You could also parse your escaped string through DOM Parser:

```
function unescapeHTML(input)
{
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
  return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}
```

in conjunction with your code...

```
var myString = "    &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.google.comp&quot;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;    &lt;li&gt;Something Else&lt;/li&gt;"

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = unescapeHTML(myString);
$("#myUL").append(div.innerHTML);
```

Which should work.

Answer (score 3):

You can also let jQuery decode it for you. Adding the encoded string with `.html()` will force jQuery to decode it. Then you can get the decoded result with `.text()`.

```js
var myString = "&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.google.comp&quot;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;    &lt;li&gt;Something Else&lt;/li&gt;"
$("#myUL").html($("<div/>").html(myString).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple function that decodes the data - then assign that value to your ul list

```
function decodeEncodedHtmlString(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

var myString = "    &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.google.comp&quot;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;    &lt;li&gt;Something Else&lt;/li&gt;"

document.getElementById('myUL').innerHTML = decodeEncodedHtmlString(myString);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nu1mne1f/)

Comment: Not at all secure for untrusted string sources, though.

Answer (score 0):

call unescape function to unescape your string

```js
var myString = "&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.google.comp&quot;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;    &lt;li&gt;Something Else&lt;/li&gt;"

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = unescape(myString);
$("#myUL").append(div.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUL">
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Decode the string first:

```js
var myString = "    &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;www.google.comp&quot;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;    &lt;li&gt;Something Else&lt;/li&gt;"

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = decodeURIComponent(myString);
$("#myUL").append(div.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUL">
</ul>
```

Comment: The string is HTML encoded, not URL encoded so `decodeURIComponent` won't work.

Comment: It isn't...? The HTML is printed to the screen, not interpreted